# Take network port as a command-line script argument

Tags: bash, smtp, ip

Modify smtp.sh so that the network port used to connect is
specified by a command-line argument (e.g., ./smtp.sh
192.168.0.15 25).

```
#!/bin/bash -
#
# smtp.sh
#
# Connect to a SMTP server
#
# Usage:
# smtp.sh <host>

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/"$1"/25
echo -e 'quit\r\n' >&3
cat <&3
```

How to modify the code? Cause I'm really new to this.  I have tried `exec 3<> /dev/tcp/host/port`, but I'm not sure of the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/"$1"/"$2"
```

now execute your script with two arguments

ex:

```
user@server:~$ ./yourScrip.sh Hostname 25
```